# Joining several raster .mbtiles?

Tags: mbtiles

I have several `.mbtiles` with no (or little) overlapping areas and I would like to merge them into one file in order to be able to serve them more easily.

I'm looking for a command line tool that can do this.

[tile-join](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) seems to work only on vector tiles. When I run to on my raster tiles it crashes:

```
tile-join first.mbtiles second .mbtiles -o combined.mbtiles
libc++abi.dylib: libc++abi.dylib: libc++abi.dylib: libc++abi.dylib: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type protozero::unknown_pbf_wire_type_exception: unknown pbf field type exceptionterminating with uncaught exception of type protozero::unknown_pbf_wire_type_exception: unknown pbf field type exceptionterminating with uncaught exception of type protozero::unknown_pbf_wire_type_exception: unknown pbf field type exceptionlibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type protozero::unknown_pbf_wire_type_exception: unknown pbf field type exceptionlibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type protozero::unknown_pbf_wire_type_exception: unknown pbf field type exception
Abort trap: 6
```

[gdal_merge.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) works on `.tiff` files but I have `.mbtiles` as input.

Update:

I managed to convert the .mbtiles to .tiff using

```
gdal_translate input.mbtiles output.tiff
gdal_translate input2.mbtiles output2.tiff
```

Then merge them using

```
gdal_merge.py -co COMPRESS=LZW  *.tiff
```

This gives me one `out.tiff` but then how to get a `.mbtiles` back? `goal_translate` gives me this error:

```
gdal_translate -of mbtiles out.tif  out.mbtiles
Input file size is 81920, 81920
0ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format.
```

any ideas?

Comment: `gdal_translate -of MBTILES merged.tif output.mbtiles -co ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=AUTO` should be working starting with gdal version >= 2.1 (though i tested it with gdal 2.3.0) Furthermore you should add some overviews to the file with `gdaladdo -r average output.mbtiles 2 4 8 16`

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLITE 3 command line tool or OGRINFO SQLITE Functions you need to connect to first database and then attach second database and insert into tiles * from others.tiles

Make sure you vacuum database and Re index tables

https://sqlite.org/cli.html
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

Do it from command line or from a SQLITE EDITOR DBBROWSER is free

Comment: Other option that sometimes.I do extract to folder of TMS TILES then combine folders then run mbutil

Comment: https://github.com/pbarry/MBTiles-extractor

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil

Comment: I was thinking about combining the TMS folders but how can I do it? mbutil cannot extract mbtiles into an existing TMS folder. I'll try  merging the SQL directly, thanks

Comment: The patch tool can do this for you too https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil/blob/d495c0a737f4bce5fde8e707fe267674be39369a/patch

Answer (score 0):

Extending GeospatialInformationTech's answer, the mbutil patch tool from https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil/blob/d495c0a737f4bce5fde8e707fe267674be39369a/patch can merge raster mbtiles where there are no overlapping tiles.